# Why and how does volatile imply atomic reads/writes?

Tags: java, volatile, atomic

First off, I'm aware that volatile does not make multiple operations (as `i++`) atomic. This question is about a *single* read or write operation.

My initial understanding was that volatile only enforces a memory barrier (i.e. other threads will be able to see updated values).

Now I've noticed that [JLS section 17.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) says that volatile additionally makes a single read or write atomic. For instance, given two threads, both writing a different value to a `volatile long x`, then x will finally represent exactly one of the values.

I'm curious how this is possible. On a 32 bit system, if two threads write to a 64 bit location in parallel and without "proper" synchronization (i.e. some kind of lock), it should be possible for the result to be a mixup. For clarity, let's use an example in which thread 1 writes 0L while thread 2 writes -1L to the same 64 bit memory location.

```
T1 writes lower 32 bit
T2 writes lower 32 bit
T2 writes upper 32 bit
T1 writes upper 32 bit
```

The result could then be 0x0000FFFF, which is undesirable. How does `volatile` prevent this scenario?

I've also read elsewhere that this does, typically, not degrade performance. How is it possible to synchronize writes with only a minor speed impact?

Answer (score 6):

Your statement that `volatile` *only enforces a memory barrier* (in the meaning, flushes the processor cache) is false. It also implies a *happens-before relationship* of read-write combinations of `volatile` values. For example:

```
class Foo {
  volatile boolean x;
  boolean y;

  void qux() {
    x = true; // volatile write
    y = true;
  }

  void baz() {
    System.out.print(x); // volatile read
    System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(y);
  }
}
```

When you run both methods from two threads, the above code will either print `true false`, `true true` or `false false` but never `false true`. Without the `volatile` keyword, you are not guaranteed the later condition because the JIT compiler might reorder statements.

The same way as the JIT compiler can assure this condition, is can guard 64-bit value reads and writes in the assembly. `volatile` values are treated explicitly by the JIT compiler to assure their atomicity. Some processor instruction sets support this directly by specific 64-bit instructions, otherwise the JIT compiler emulates it.

The JVM is more complex as you might expect it to be and it is often explained without full scope. Consider [reading this excellent article](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/) which covers all the details.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't the *happens before* established because of the *memory barrier*?

Comment: Yes, a *memory barrier* (maybe it's more clear when you use the synonym *fence*) is an ordering instruction.

Comment: So, just using the term *memory barrier / fence* implicitly means a *happens before* has been established, *always*?

Comment: Well, a memory barrier by itself is little descriptive. A fence is established between instructions. If there was another `volatile` variable `z` in the above example and you would read `z` instead of `x`, no guarantees were given.

Comment: Even then the read to *z* is guaranteed to give me the latest value (because it is declared as volatile.). Thanks for the explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

volatile assures that what a thread reads is the latest values at that point, but it doesn't synchronize two writes.

If a thread writes a normal variable, it keeps the values within the thread until some certain events happen. If a thread writes a volatile variable, it change the memory of the variable immediately.

Comment: From what I understand OP started by saying they already _know_ this and are asking _how_ this is handled with volatiles (probably asking about how it is implemented)

Comment: You have to deal with synchronizing yourself rather than considering 'volatile'.

Answer (score 0):

> On a 32 bit system, if two threads write to a 64 bit location in parallel and without "proper" synchronization (i.e. some kind of lock), it should be possible for the result to be a mixup

This is indeed what can happen if a variable isn't marked `volatile`. Now, what does the system do if the field is marked `volatile`? Here is a resource that explains this: http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html

> Nearly all processors support at least a coarse-grained barrier instruction, often just called a Fence, that guarantees that all loads and stores initiated before the fence will be strictly ordered before any load or store initiated after the fence [...] if available, you can implement volatile store as an atomic instruction (for example XCHG on x86) and omit the barrier. This may be more efficient if atomic instructions are cheaper than StoreLoad barriers

Essentially the processors provide facilities to implement the guarantee, and what facility is available depends on the processor.